# Spritekit and swift - How to get data back from testers during testing

Tags: ios, swift, testing, build, sprite-kit

I'm building a 2d platformer that is level based. Game is built with spritekit and swift for the iOS Platform.

Each level has a "time" challenge. Basic bronze, silver, and gold medals. If you can complete the level by the times for the medals you will unlock that medal for that level.

When I send out a build for testers, I want to get data back that tells me how fast the testers complete the levels, so I can use this data to better judge what times I should set for the time medals in each level.

I'm curious how I would gather this information.

Having a hard time finding information on how to go about this.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

Use a leaderboard based on time.

There's no need to publish the results, or make an interface that displays them, you can simply use the systems of Game Center to provide you with this information.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Achievements/Achievements.html

Comment: This would work and some thing I'm wanting to implement into the game. My only issue is will I be able to log each time a player completes a level and the time associated. Example: player1 plays level  1 five times. I want to see his how long it took the player to complete the level each time. To judge how quickly the player learns to complete levels faster, or measure if there is a progression, instead of it just tracking the "best" time... Again I'm not familiar with how the achievements works and if it has logging capabilities. Definitely something I will be looking into. Thanks!

Comment: On that page, start reading from the Leaderboards title, a fair way down the page. Everything you need, and much more, is there.

Comment: Thanks again for the info, I’ll have to test it out to see how it works, but definitely looks like it could work. I’m assuming testers will need to enable Game Center for it to work

Comment: No need for them to enable game center, you can just use these mechanics to create your "scoring" and "leaderboards" and then have this info sent back to you any way you like.

Comment: Even better... thanks for the tips! I’ll mark it correct after I get it all functioning. Thanks again